# Use lan-connected printer within VMware

Tags: printer, lan, vmware-player

I have a printer connnect via LAN to the host-PC (windows 7). I want to use it from a virtual windows XP guest within Vmware but XP does not seem to find the printer, any ideas?

BTW, I do have a network connection to the router where the printer is connected.

Answer (score 1):

You can [add a networked printer to XP](http://uis.georgetown.edu/software/documentation/winxp/winxp.network.printer.html).

Comment: Well, i know, but XP does not find the printer. Must have something to do with the networkconnection and VMware.

Comment: Is your VM on the same subnet as the host? If not, you won't see the printer. To be sure it's on the same subnet, set the VM network adapter to "bridged" instead of "NAT".

Answer (score 0):

This should just work.  If it does not then you need to check if you installed the VM in 'host only networking' (in other words: dear Xp Vm, never talk to anything but the wi7 host and thus never reach anything on the network).

If set to normal (bridged) mode it should just work.

If set to NAtted mode it should also work.